# How can I dynamically creating threads to execute web requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this code I have written that requests a fileserver for a CSV, loads the data into a data frame. The flat file I am reading from will contain a lot of URLs so I would like to spin up multiple workers based on the load to read these urls from and create the data frame. How can I do this? I am not exactly sure how concurrent.futures works but that seems promising. I was also curious as to how I can catch 404s and other HTTPS errors while passing read_csv to pandas.

Code:

```
def read_files():
    t0 = time.process_time()
    files = []
    with open('data/url') as f:
        for line in f:
            files.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

    df_list = []
    for file in files:
        try:
            df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
        except ParserError as pe:
            logging.error(f'Parsing Error on {file}. Error: {pe}')
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    t1 = time.process_time()
    print(f'It took {t1 - t0} seconds, to read and fill the dataframe.')
    return df


def run_calculations(df):
    average = round(df[' age'].mean())
    median = df[' age'].median()
    print(f'The Average Age: {average}, The Median Age is {median}')
    print(df[df[' age'] == median])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_calculations(read_files())
```

Comment: this is almost an example in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread pool and call your function from it.

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.submit(read_files)
```

Comment: I am going to try implementing this, but won't it cause an issue by returning multiple data frames? ( I am very inexperienced in this area) my thought is that different threads will be producing different returns on that function.